# What is EtherType 9C9D?

Tags: ethernet

An ISP came and set up their radios the other day. After connecting my router to the radio and configuring it with the IP address, netmask, and gateway which they specified, I can't ping their gateway (it doesn't even answer ARP queries).

However, doing a packet trace on the radio's Ethernet port, I can see a constant stream of frames with EtherType 9C9D. They are directed to 2 specific MAC addresses, and it seems that something is sending them once per second.

Here is an excerpt from `tcpdump`:

`` 11:57:58.401652 00:15:67:64:f5:55 (oui Unknown) > 00:00:07:d6:c4:f3 (oui Unknown), ethertype Unknown (0x9c9d), length 62:
        0x0000:  8d00 1000 8b00 1065 8d00 1000 0000 002a  .......e.......*
        0x0010:  0260 d742 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  .`.B............
        0x0020:  0000 0007 0000 0015 6764 f555 0103 f2f2  ........gd.U....
11:57:58.901660 00:15:67:64:f5:55 (oui Unknown) > 00:15:67:00:00:02 (oui Unknown), ethertype Unknown (0x9c9d), length 62:
        0x0000:  8d00 1000 8b00 1065 8d00 1000 0000 002a  .......e.......*
        0x0010:  0260 d746 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  .`.F............
        0x0020:  0000 0007 0000 0015 6764 f555 0103 f2ee  ........gd.U.... ``

Google is failing me here. Does anyone know what those frames are???

Comment: Would you mind posting one of those frames? Sounds like some sort of keepalive/health check.

Comment: @RickyBeam, thanks for your comment. `tcpdump` output added. Please let me know if I should post a pcap file or something instead.

Comment: `-XX` please, so we see the *entire* packet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those look like some sort of topology discovery mechanism (like cdp or lldp.)

(It's as if it's searching for an NMS or link-partner to know how to configure itself. But I'm not familiar with how Radwin's gear works. I would hope your ISP has any required documentation and experience with this stuff.)

Comment: Do you think these frames are originating from the radio on our side, or from something on the other side (passing through the radio link)?

Comment: There are two Radwin MACs involved, but the second one (00:15:67:00:00:02) seems suspicious since it's #2.  There's also a Xerox MAC involved, do you have anything on your side that might have a Xerox ethernet phy in it?  For wireless provisioning purposes a stream of small and otherwise useless packets could be used to either generate signal stat data in spite of a lack of other traffic, or detect a layer 2 loop in the case that the radio is being used in a mesh topology.

Answer (score 0):

The Ethertype bytes will get altered to something unique if additional VLAN tagging is in use on the link.  This might also explain your lack of connectivity.  Perhaps the vendor requires a specific VLAN for normal traffic?

Comment: If those frames were VLAN tagged, the "EtherType" should be 8100.